# RS-232 baud rates and wire length effect on serial bits received

Tags: serial-port

If there is this rs232 wire and it is longer than spec and the baud rates are not compensated for , will there be baud rate mismatch... i.e. the incoming serial bits will be held high or low for shorter ...and you start seeing incorrect messages on the receive side ? is that the same as having a wire with more capacitance or a wire with more interference /cross-talk? , if the message takes longer to reach the receiver without losses, what happens then on the receiver side , is it just message received later then expected?

Comment: It is not possible to specify what problems will occur if you do not follow the specifications. If the problem can be stated, it is itself a specification. It is important to consider the possibilities of various problems, but trying to get some confirmation about it is a waste of time.

Comment: The RS-232 spec mentions a maximum cable length and maximum capacitance.  The problem(s) caused by too long a cable is/are not in the time domain (i.e. *"the message takes longer to reach the receiver"* is not a concern), but rather in the frequency domain (i.e. bandwidth is reduced and slew rate is lowered, so the max baudrate is limited).  There is no *"baud rate mismatch"* or *"message received later"*, but level changes are slowed from sharp, squared edges to slow, rounded changes.  Potential for mis-sampling the bits increases.

Comment: @sawdust, How about writing it as an answer?